# Get java.lang.NullPointerException reading size app folder

Tags: java, android, apk

I want read the size of app folder. I can do it also with system app without problems but the "normal" app folder it gets me problems. I do in this way:

```
File apk = new File("/data/app");
        if (apk.exists()){
            float apksize=getFolderSize(apk)/(1024f*1024f);

            apk.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.apk)+ " " +"<b>" +String.format("%.2f", apksize)+ " " + "Mb" + "</b>"
                            ));
        } else {
            apk.setText(devicefragment.this.getResources().getString(R.string.folderapknotfound));
        }
```

and then the method for folder size

```
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
            long size = 0;
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    // System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
                    size += file.length();
                } else
                    size += getFolderSize(file);
            }
            return size;
            }
```

for every other folders i try it works well.. this one nope. The logcat return:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myapp.deviceinfo.getFolderSize(devicefragment.java:316)
at com.myapp.deviceinfo.onCreateView(devicefragment.java:179)
...
```

where line 316 is : `size += getFolderSize(file);` and line 179 is: `float apksize=getFolderSize(apk)/(1024f*1024f);`

i don't know why it crashes honestly.. no root needs for this operation.

edit:

i tried:

```
public static long getFolderSize(File dir) {
            long size = 0;
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
if (file == null) {
   continue;
}
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    // System.out.println(file.getName() + " " + file.length());
                    size += file.length();
                } else
                    size += getFolderSize(file);
            }
            return size;
            }
```

but crashes anyway

Comment: What happens if you change `getFolderSize` to *Myclass*.getFolderSize?

Comment: You could also set a debug breakpoint at line `File apk = new File("/data/app");` in the IDE you are using. Step forward one step at the time and see which variables that are null. :)

Comment: nothing..crashes. But for the other folders works.. Even for "system/app"

Comment: Try changing `if (apk.exists()){` to `if (apk != null && apk.exists()){`

Comment: Nope... crahses persist :(

Comment: Tricky question since I cannot try it out myself. The best approach for you is to either debug or print all variables at the lines where the exception is thrown, to find which variable is null.

Comment: well.. maybe for app folder needs root? i don't know.. it's strange.. but maybe works with root.

Comment: `honestly.. no root needs for this operation` Yes it does i think.

Answer (score 0):

One (or more) of your `File` objects named `file` is null in the loop in `getFolderSize`. The easiest way to fix this is to ignore objects that are null by adding a null check inside the loop:

```
for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
    if(file == null) {
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you mean inside of loop? after `for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {`?

Comment: Yes! :) Updating question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
```

`dir.listFiles()` can return null. So better determine first and check for `null` before use.

Comment: how is possible? the folder exists! you say that root is required... but why for system app folder not?

Comment: how you got any suggestion?

Comment: For what exactly? And i did NOT say that root IS required. Only that i thought so. Please reread. But now that i think more then yes pretty sure that root is required.